# How to show all divs that contain the similar combination of classes

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress

I would like to show specific posts on a Wordpress page and hide all others. What posts are to be shown, should depend on checkboxes checked on top of the page. A checkbox corresponds with a class. When (for example) two checkboxes are checked (two classes selected in essence), only posts containing at least those two classes in their wrapping div (besides a possible third or fourth class they may have) should be shown (and all the other posts hidden) instantly on the page.

Does anyone of you know how to pull this off?

I already managed to get the tags assigned to a post in the CMS and transfer those tags to the wrapping div of that very post as its class names, so far so good.

How to write the last piece of needed code from scratch I find very difficult to do with the small amount of knowledge I have. I understand that first the desired classes should be gathered (selected through the checked checkboxes). Then a condition should be formed (class1 AND class3 AND class7 have been selected). Then, if that condition is true for a post (‘your wrapping div contains class1, class3 and class7’), only then the post should be shown. The post could also (for example) contain class2, that’s fine, the filter though is made up of the combination of class1, class3 and class7 being present within the wrapper div, as long as that’s true, it may be shown).

I’m sure this should be a stroll through the park for a lot of you, for me it’s still pretty hard to realise from scratch, so any help you guys could give me is highly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

---

Thanks for your response so far, guys, closest thing I found online so far is this:

```
$("#filters :checkbox").click(function() {
   $("div").hide();
   $("#filters :checkbox:checked").each(function() {
       $("." + $(this).val()).show();
   });
});
```

It comes from this setup: http://jsfiddle.net/6wYzw/41/ > here it shows a post when its wrapping div contains classX AND/OR classY, see its working example. I reckon the part where it says

```
$("." + $(this).val()).show();
```

... needs to be adjusted, so that right here all the checked checkboxes/classes so far are taken into account using AND, not OR. Is this the only line which actually has to be adjusted in order to make my desired setup work the way I want it too?

@Lisrael > all posts should be displayed at first, then the filter starts to kick in as soon as checkboxes are starting to be clicked just like you said indeed.

Comment: Blux, can you please provide the code you are working on?  That's a very important item to include in all questions.  Also, are you using a query loop to get the posts that meet specific criteria and then you are trying to filter the results using check boxes the user clicks, is that correct?

Comment: What have you actually tried so far?

Comment: Hi guys, just added to my post following your questions, see above!

Comment: I've done a few similar things in the past, to be honest your use case seems like a good fit to use Isotope https://isotope.metafizzy.co/. If you'd rather just use your own code I can dig out an example though.

Comment: Sephsekla, Isotope looks like a powerful tool indeed! I’m a bit worried about drowning in all its possibilities though and didn’t find my use case, I indeed think I prefer clean and relevant to-the-point code. I need a few lines of code that say > gather the classes that follow from their corresponding checkboxes having been checked > see which posts have at least those specific classes in each of them > do they each have at least all of those specific classes then show them > hide all of the other posts.

Comment: Found an example of Isotope tonight which actually does what I’m after: https://codepen.io/desandro/pen/btFfG - way too much code in here though, hard to adjust for me, all content is being generated through the jquery, so, difficult for me to simplify. It’s a good example though of how I’d like my filter to work.

Answer (score 0):

Found out how to do this! With the help of an example which came close already and lot's of 'sub'examples here and there. See the code.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
    <h3 align="center">Boardgamefilter</h3>

<form name="gamesettings">
<input type="checkbox" name="gamesetting" value="1p">1p<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="gamesetting" value="2p">2p<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="gamesetting" value="3p">3p<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="gamesetting" value="4p">4p<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="gamesetting" value="5p">5p<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="gamesetting" value="6plus">6plus<br />
<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="gamesetting" value="15m">15m<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="gamesetting" value="30m">30m<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="gamesetting" value="45m">45m<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="gamesetting" value="60m">60m<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="gamesetting" value="90m">90m<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="gamesetting" value="120mplus">120mplus
<br />
<br />
<input type="button" name="Un_CheckAll" value="Reset"
onClick="UnCheckAll(document.gamesettings.gamesetting)">
</form>

<br />
<br />

<div id="boardgames">
<div class="1p 2p 15m 30m" style="display: block;">1p 2p 15m 30m</div>
<div class="1p 2p 30m 45m" style="display: block;">1p 2p 30m 45m</div>
<div class="2p 30m 60m" style="display: block;">2p 30m 60m</div>
</div>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $('input[name=gamesetting]').change(function(){

        var arr = []
        $(":checkbox").each(function(){
           if($(this).is(":checked")){
             arr.push($(this).val())
           }
        })
        var vals = arr.join(".")
        var str = (".") + vals

        $('#boardgames div').hide();
        $('#boardgames div' + (str)).show();

    })

    function UnCheckAll(chk) {
        for (i = 0; i < chk.length; i++)
        chk[i].checked = false ;
        $('#boardgames div').show();
    }

</script>

</body>
</html>
```